# Reading formula calculated value from excel cell in c#

Tags: c#, excel, linq-to-excel

I am using linqtoexcel for reading from a excel sheet. the problem i face is that i can't read the formula calculated value from a cell, instead i get the actual value of the cell. Is there any way to read the end value of the cell from the excel sheet using linqtoexcel or by some other means.

Comment: Maybe you could re-calculate the cell in c#?

Comment: its not that actually. Is it possible read the formula for the cell? i'm importing data from user mentioned excel sheet mate.

Answer (score 1):

linqtoexcel uses OleDB to access the sheet's data, and since OleDB does not allow the formulas to be accessed, you can't read the formula from the excel cell. You can only view the value for the cell.

Comment: Is there any other way around to read those calculated values other than linqtoexcel?